# Drag & Drop Tiles - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tiles

I´d like to Drag Tiles from one NavigationBar to a Dashboard. (Using Visual Studio 2015, C#, and WPF) Now I´m stuck to one question; Which DataFormat has the Content of a Tile? Only Image? But how do I use/cache it?

```
private void tileFrom_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Tile tileFrom = e.Source as Tile;

    if (tileFrom!= null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {   
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tileFrom,
                             tileFrom.Content,
                             DragDropEffects.All);

    }
}

private void tileTo_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Tile tileTo = e.Source as Tile;
    string draggedText = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
    tileTo.Content = draggedText;
}
```

Instead of the `StringFormat` there must be some other way... Please help!

Answer (score 1):

in Drag and Drop, you can examine what formats are available using [`e.Data.GetFormats()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557793(v=vs.110).aspx) - I find it more useful to get the object and then check the type.

```
object data = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats[0]);
var someTypeData = data as SomeType;
if(someTypeData != null) {...}
```